# Bounty Boost and Resurrect or Zero Response Bounty Return

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

I put out a bounty recently and got zero comments and zero answers.  It then expired.

I'd still like to get this question answered, and (if the feature existed) I would even go so far as to increase the bounty amount.  But given that I just put 50 reputation towards getting no response at all, it seems like a waste to put an additional 100 reputation towards it and hope for the best.

Here's two feature ideas that might help in this scenario:

1. The ability to resurrect an expired bounty by adding more rep to it.
2. Getting bounty returned if there is *zero* response (no comments, no answers) to it.

Neither of these features seem particularly game-able, and would make it less of a risk to put bounties on uncommon issues.

Comment: #2 won't happen.  #1...maybe, but you'd need to put forth a very strong argument for it.

Comment: My argument is that I think answering a question well should be worth all the bounty points ever put towards it (by the person awarding it), not just the most recent batch of points.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. The ability to resurrect an expired bounty by adding more rep to it.

That's already possible, and you're giving the example yourself. A 50-point bounty can be doubled three times, and you can post infinitely many 500-point bounties (as long as you have the reputation, of course).

> 2. Getting bounty returned if there is zero response (no comments, no answers) to it.

An often-used analogy to bounties on Stack Exchange are advertisements. If you advertise in a local newspaper, TV, Google or LinkedIn, and do not get satisfactory response (or none at all), do you get a refund from those companies? One could argue that at least online, you can pay for actual clicks instead of page impressions, but a bounty *does* increase the view count of a question.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see the ability to resurrect and add to my expired bounty anywhere.  Do you know how it's done?

Comment: Oh, you meant that posting a new bounty (costing you 100 reputation) should be combined with the original 50-point bounty for a 150 point bounty?

Comment: Also, I do see the analogy, but I'm not sure if the analogy comes from the implementation or vise versa.  Given that it's called "bounty" and not "ad", it would seem the analogy describes the state more than the intent.

Comment: Something along those lines, yes.  If someone does finally answer it, I think it should be worth all of the bounty points put towards it, not just the most recent batch.

Comment: I see. I don't think that's likely going to happen, and you can always post another bounty to 'reward an existing answer'. This will lead to a net loss of reputation, but OTOH the [additional upvotes to the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329199/4751173) (and probably to the answer as well) are a net reputation gain.

Comment: I don't expect it to happen.  But if it did, there would be more incentive for me to put out bigger bounties, and I think that might be a goal of someone.

Comment: It'd be kind of like a "double or nothing" sunken-cost-fallacy feature, which I can seem some ethical issues with, but in terms of benefiting the site, I think it would.